# Redirect to another page after if condition

Tags: php

After submitting data from a form, I want to be redirected to a page, here's my code :

```
<form action="#result" method="POST">
  <input name="zipcode" type="text" placeholder="Your ZipCode" />
  <input name="zipcode_submit" type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>

<div id="result">

<?php 

    if(isset($_POST['zipcode_submit'])) {
        header("Location: http://twitter.com");
    }

?>

</div>
```

It does not work for me and I don't know why

Thanks for your help

Comment: header must be the first output. Move form after

Comment: working for me perfectly. check your file extension. it must be `.php`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to shift the php code, above the form tag,i.e

```
 <?php 

    if(isset($_POST['zipcode_submit'])) {
        header("Location: http://twitter.com");
    }

   ?>
```

above

```
<form action="#result" method="POST">
```

Comment: And if I remove the div #result and update this line like this <form action="" method="POST"> I think it should work too, Am I wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [php.net docs](http://php.net/manual/de/function.header.php) regarding the header function. It has to be the first output to the website. Put your form at the end of the file.

```
  <html>
<?php
    /* this will produce an error, header must be the first output on the website */
    header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
    exit;
    ?>
```

You should place a exit; after the header statement, to fully prevent the following code from being executed.